# PHP - Find substrings between two regex expressions

Tags: php, regex

I need a function that returns all substrings between a regex expression that matches anything and a delimiter.

```
$str = "{random_one}[SUBSTRING1] blah blah blah {random_two}[SUBSTRING2] blah blah blah{random_one}[SUBSTRING3]";

$resultingArray = getSubstrings($str)

$resultingArray should result in:
array(
    [0]: "SUBSTRING1",
    [1]: "SUBSTRING2",
    [2]: "SUBSTRING3"
)
```

I've been messing with regex with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit unclear. You need everything between the brackets? Try [this](https://3v4l.org/GS7YP).

Comment: @ishegg yes everything between the brackets after {anything}[ this_is_what_i_need ] - i'll check that out

Comment: Oh, if there needs to be a string between curly before, try [this instead](https://3v4l.org/gmh9q). The matches are in `$matches[1]`

Comment: @ishegg $matches[1] is near perfect! Do you know how to remove the brackets from it though??

Comment: Leave them out of the capturing group - I'll write an answer, just a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with this regular expression:

```
/{.+?}\[(.+?)\]/i
```

**Details**

```
{.+?}   # anything between curly brackets, one or more times, ungreedily
\[      # a bracket, literally
(.+?)   # anything one or more times, ungreedily. This is your capturing group - what you're after
\]      # close bracket, literally
i       # flag for case insensitivity
```

In PHP it would look like this:

```
<?php
$string = "{random_one}[SUBSTRING1] blah [SUBSTRINGX] blah blah {random_two}[SUBSTRING2] blah blah blah{random_one}[SUBSTRING3]";
preg_match_all("/{.+?}\[(.+?)\]/i", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LPSnD)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you so much!

Comment: It's no problem. Good luck!